# How does oracle execute an sql statement?

Tags: oracle

such as:

```
select country 
  from table1 
 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
 where table1.name='a' and table2.name='b'
 group by country
```

after the parse, which part will be executed first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to know the execution plan chosen by Oracle. You can get that ouput from Oracle itself:

```
set serveroutput off
< your query with hint "/*+ gather_plan_statistics */" inserted after SELECT >
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'last allstats'));
```

See here for an explanation how to read a query plan: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/ex_plan.htm#i16971

Be aware however that the choice of a query plan is not fixed. Oracle tries to find the currently best query plan, based on available statistics data.

Comment: For useful information, you need to add the hint /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ to your query, or set the parameter statistics_level to ALL.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I knew I forgot something

Comment: Thanks for you answer,i have another question,how oracle choice query plan,and how to generate query plan,thanks.

Comment: @Robin To put it simply: Oracle chooses the plan which minimizes execution cost, where cost if defined as number of disk accesses. That being said, it is a complex subject. Perhaps you could start with reading in "Concepts" http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/sqllangu.htm#sthref959 and afterwards take up the Optimizer in http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/sqllangu.htm#i8709 .

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of places you can find the order in which [SQL is executed](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm):

> 1. FROM clause
> 2. WHERE clause
> 3. GROUP BY clause
> 4. HAVING clause
> 5. SELECT clause
> 6. ORDER BY clause

But note that this is the "theoretical" order - SQL engines are allowed to perform the operations in other orders, provided that the end result appears to have been produced by using the above order.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the free tool SQL*Developer from Oracle, then you can click a button to get the explain plan.

A quick explanation is at http://www.seeingwithc.org/sqltuning.html